# Why can't I call a MySQL stored function in a prepared query via PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, stored-functions

I have the following query in a prepared statement:

```
SELECT 
  cid, cname, cemail, count_client_locations(cid) AS loc_cnt
FROM 
  clients 
WHERE isactive = 1 ORDER BY cname ASC
```

I have a stored function on the server `count_client_locations`. The query part of the function looks like this:

```
RETURN (SELECT COUNT(lid) FROM locations WHERE linked_client = cid);
```

When I run the SQL in MySQL Workbench, it returns the desired result:

```
cid | cname       | cemail            | loc_cnt
------------------------------------------------
2   | Acme Inc    | fred@example.com  | 3
1   | Example Ind | alice@example.com | 5
3   | Foobar Inc  | joe@example.com   | 0
1   | Barfoo Ltd  | hello@example.com | 1
```

When I run that via PHP mysqli prepared statement, it fails to prepare it (`Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object`). If i take out the call to the function, it works fine.

**EDIT PHP code:**

```
$sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT cid, cname, cemail, count_client_locations(cid) AS loc_cnt FROM clients WHERE isactive = 1 ORDER BY cname ASC");
$sql->execute();
```

So why does this query work in MySQL workbench, and not in the PHP code, and is there anything I can do to fix it?

Comment: @Drew - I am not sure if I follow what you mean. I got what wrong? The query?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php/12769983#12769983'

Comment: nothing really revolutionary about it

Comment: so where is your php code?

Comment: try count(cid)..... showing more of your editphp code might helps.

Comment: It looks as though your `prepare()` is failing. What does your webserver's error.log say? Also, the contents of `$conn->error` might be enlightening.

Comment: var_dump( get_class( $conn ) ); just before prepare statement if it is ok, var_dump( $sql )  after prepare statement and let me know what you are getting .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, answering my own question as to why the query was working in MySQL Workbench and not in the PHP code is because I wasn't specifying which database for the stored function call:

```
SELECT 
  cid, cname, cemail, DBName.count_client_locations(cid) AS loc_cnt
FROM 
  clients 
WHERE isactive = 1 ORDER BY cname ASC
```

Comment: You can probably also specify a default database for the connection to use, at which point you won't need to specify it for every statement (it's an optional parameter when creating a new mysqli connection.)

Answer (score 0):

You're getting an error message `Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object`.

Just to be clear, this is a PHP error message, not a MySQL error message. The error is not related to your query string or to your database in any way at all.

Your code looks like this: `$conn->prepare(...)`.

The error is occurring because PHP doesn't recognise the `$conn` variable. You might think `$conn` is the MySQL connection object, but PHP is looking at `$conn` when you call it and seeing `null` (or possibly `false` or some other non object value). This is why it is giving this error.

You haven't shown us enough code for me to explain *why* it might be doing this; possibly you're in a function and haven't passed `$conn` into it, but there are other possible reasons as well. As I can't be certain, I'll leave you to work it out from there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Spudley. I did mention that if I take out the call to the stored function in the query itself, the query works as it should (less the `count_client_locations(cid) AS loc_cnt` in the selected columns. I did also mention that the query fails to prepare. My actual question was why the original query works on the MySQL Workbench, but not in the PHP code (as I thought if it works in one it works in the other). However I just fixed my problem.

Comment: Yeah; the `prepare` was failing (at a MySQL level) and returning `false`, and because you then called `prepare()` on it rather than checking the return value for an error state, you were effectively executing `false->prepare()` in PHP, which led to the PHP error you actually saw.